# Fastest way to repeatedly subset a data frame with varying condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, subset

I have a data frame like the one (toy example) below

```
> dt
 A B C D
1 0 0 0 1
2 0 0 0 1
3 0 1 0 1
4 1 1 0 0
5 1 0 0 1
```

and a list of single row data frames, like below

```
[[1]]
  A C
1 1 0

[[2]]
  A D
1 0 1

.
.
```

I then need to repeatedly subset the larger data frame dt based on the smaller data frames such that for each of the smaller data frames, I get all and only those rows of dt where the columns that match the smaller data frame columns have values that match the values in the smaller data frame. So the result for the two small dfs shown above should be a list like below, created by subsetting dt or joining dt and the small data frames appropriately:

```
[[1]]
  A B C D
2 1 0 0 1
5 1 1 0 0

[[2]]
  A B C D
1 0 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 1

.
.
```

After studying answers to similar questions on SO and elsewhere, I am still unsure what would be the fastest way to achieve this. In particular, I have tried using data.table for this, but I believe I am doing something wrong, as I'm unable to make it particularly fast (still new to data.table...). Setting a key doesn't seem to be that helpful, as the key(s) would have to be reset repeatedly. I have also tried dplyr semi_join(), but that wasn't faster than base for me. Below is a full toy example with some benchmarking results in the comments. The detailed results are not so important -- the point is that the variant using only base is the fastest, and I seriously doubt that my attempt with e.g. data.table is the optimal data.table solution. Any suggestions for doing this more efficiently would be greatly appreciated, the actual use case involves repeating this kind of subsetting/joining many more times, and is currently a major bottleneck.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1L)

# create toy data frame
dt <- data.frame(A = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T), 
                 B = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T),
                 C = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T),
                 D = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T))

#> dt
#   A B C D
# 1 0 0 1 0
# 2 0 1 1 1
# 3 0 0 0 0
# 4 0 0 1 1
# 5 0 1 0 1


# create a list of small toy data frames comprising 1 row 
# and a subset of dt columns (but in same order as in dt)
cvals <- replicate(10, dt[sample(1:nrow(dt), 1), sort(sample(1:length(dt), 2)) ], simplify = FALSE)

# > head(cvals,2)
# [[1]]
#   B D
# 4 0 1
# 
# [[2]]
#   B D
# 4 0 1

### loop over cvals and subset dt to find rows where 
### matching columns have matching values

## base 

# identify which dt columns are found in the cvals df, paste values of those columns
# over all rows, paste cvals df column values, find a match, subset dt with match index
dtsubs_base <- lapply(cvals, function(x)
  dt[which(do.call(paste0, dt[, which(names(dt) %in% names(x))]) %in% do.call(paste0, x)),])

## dplyr
dtsubs_dplyr <- lapply(cvals, function(x) semi_join(dt, x))

## data.table
cvals <- lapply(cvals, as.data.table) #convert to data.tables
dt <- as.data.table(dt) #convert to data table


# attempt 1
# resetting the key at every iteration, which undermines the point of setting a key...
# doing something wrong here
dtsubs_DT1 <- lapply(cvals, function(x){setkeyv(dt, names(x)); return(dt[J(x)])})


# attempt 2
# with 'on ='
dtsubs_DT2 <- lapply(cvals, function(x) dt[x, on = names(x)])

#verify that the results are equal
all(mapply(dplyr::setequal, dtsubs_base, dtsubs_dplyr, dtsubs_DT1, dtsubs_DT2))
#[1] TRUE


###TIMING

##data.table

DT1_bench <- microbenchmark(lapply(cvals, function(x){setkeyv(dt, names(x)); return(dt[J(x)])}))

# Unit: milliseconds
#                                                                 expr     min       lq    mean  median       uq     max neval
# lapply(cvals, function(x) { setkeyv(dt, names(x)) return(dt[J(x)]) }) 22.0109 23.98225 25.7736 25.0835 26.51385 44.8583  100


DT2_bench <- microbenchmark(lapply(cvals, function(x) dt[x, on = names(x)])) # slower than DT attempt 1

# Unit: milliseconds
#                                             expr     min     lq     mean   median     uq     max neval
#  lapply(cvals, function(x) dt[x, on = names(x)]) 25.7943 28.955 30.65348 30.24595 31.862 40.3184   100


##base -- fastest

cvals <- lapply(cvals, as.data.frame) # convert back to data.frames
dt <- as.data.frame(dt)

base_bench <- microbenchmark(lapply(cvals, function(x)
  dt[which(do.call(paste0, dt[, which(names(dt) %in% names(x))]) %in% do.call(paste0, x)),]))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                                                                  expr
#  lapply(cvals, function(x) dt[which(do.call(paste0, dt[, which(names(dt) %in% names(x))]) %in% do.call(paste0, x)), ])
#    min     lq    mean median    uq     max neval
#  706.1 741.65 1067.88 774.95 898.5 10741.9   100

##dplyr

dplyr_bench <- microbenchmark(lapply(cvals, function(x) semi_join(dt, x)))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                         expr    min      lq     mean median    uq     max neval
#  lapply(cvals, function(x) semi_join(dt, x)) 5.0085 5.60725 6.841974 6.5469 7.683 12.1848   100
```

Comment: Hi, what are the actual dimensions and number of iterations for your actual problem? You might want to generate a huge data.table from the list before performing any joins

Comment: This (subsetting) happens in a function, so the dimensions vary based on input. I should mention that in the real case, the number of columns in the smaller data frames can vary (but is always a subset of columns of the larger), sorry for not making this clear.  So combining them might not be an option? But as an example, if the larger df has only about 150 rows and 10 columns, and I have about 1500 iterations of the subsetting, and this has to be repeated for many different dfs, the performance of the function takes a noticable hit.

Comment: It is hard to beat the elegance of `dt[x, on = names(x)])`.
One thing that might make sense if some columns are much more common in cvals, is to make them the primary keys (`setkeyv(dt, names(sort(table(sapply(cvals, names)))))`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the same cvals as you, but with this example data

```
set.seed(1L)

dt <- data.frame(A = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T), 
                 B = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T),
                 C = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T),
                 D = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = T))

cvals <- replicate(10, dt[sample(1:nrow(dt), 1), sort(sample(1:length(dt), 2)) ], simplify = FALSE)
```

we can acheive the task in Base-R with

```
lapply(cvals, function(x) dt[apply(dt[,colnames(x)],1, function(y) all(unlist(y) == unlist(x))),])

[[1]]
  A B C D
2 1 0 0 1
5 1 1 0 0

[[2]]
  A B C D
1 0 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 1

[[3]]
  A B C D
5 1 1 0 0

[[4]]
  A B C D
1 0 0 0 1
2 1 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 1

[[5]]
  A B C D
1 0 0 0 1
2 1 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 1

[[6]]
  A B C D
1 0 0 0 1
2 1 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 1

[[7]]
  A B C D
4 0 1 0 1

[[8]]
  A B C D
4 0 1 0 1

[[9]]
  A B C D
1 0 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 1

[[10]]
  A B C D
2 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check how this works with the use case I have in mind, but for me, `lapply(cvals, function(x)
  dt[which(do.call(paste0, dt[, which(names(dt) %in% names(x))]) %in% do.call(paste0, x)),])` seems to be a bit faster with the small example, for whatever reason.